# How to Encrypt pk from django url without using any package?

Tags: python, django, encryption, django-urls

how to encrypt and decrypt pk from django url without using any package
basically i have a url like

```
example.com/update/1
```

where pk=1

i want to encrypt the pk like pk 1 = 345345435cgsfd2asdfaas

Comment: ok try to build your own function

Comment: If you don't want numeric ids, you could use [UUIDFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) for your model primary key.

Comment: You could also use another field (if unique=True) of your model in the url if you don't want to expose the pk

Comment: This isn't a solution and I'm not sure if it's relevant here, but perhaps you should reconsider what you're doing https://security.stackexchange.com/a/762/71688

Answer (score 6):

There is no inbuld method, to do this I think, but using [TimestampSigner](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signing/#verifying-timestamped-values), you can do the following:

Using TimestampSigner, you can encrypt your PK, and later decrypt when you want the original string.

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> from django.core.signing import TimestampSigner
>>> signer = TimestampSigner()
>>> value = signer.sign(str(pk)) # encrypt the PK.
>>> value
'1:1NMg5H:oPVuCqlJWmChm1rA2lyTUtelC-c'
>>> value = value.replace(pk,"") # doing this because, it append the original primary key + encrypted string.
>>> value # use this PK to show in the URL.
'1NMg5H:oPVuCqlJWmChm1rA2lyTUtelC-c'
>>> repack = "{}:{}".format(pk,value) # When you want back the original PK, add the PK + encrypted string.
>>>repack
'1:1NMg5H:oPVuCqlJWmChm1rA2lyTUtelC-c'
>>> signer.unsign(repack) # decrypt the PK.
'1'
```

Hope this will be helpfull for you.

Comment: but how can i decrypt the pk back in view

Comment: I have update the code, you can do it by using `.unsign()` method. details here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signing/#using-the-low-level-api

Comment: but how to i pass the encrypted pk to my url in urls.py

Comment: what is the problem in urls.py ? 

are you adding `urlpatterns` ??

EG: 
`urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]`

Comment: url(r'^Update/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.Update, name='Update')          -- my url is localhost/update/1  i want   localhost/update/Sd3234%$34232  pk must but encrypted

Comment: how come the user knows pk when repacking is the url is `user/1NMg5H:oPVuCqlJWmChm1rA2lyTUtelC-c` ?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to expose `pk` to the url then you can use `signing.dumps` while encrypting and `signing.loads` on decryption. Serialized object is signed using TimestampSigner.

```
>>> from django.core import signing
>>> value = signing.dumps({"pk": "25"})
>>> value
'eyJwayI6IjI1In0:1g9Q4d:RJRYtpklLqaa3ey9c4d4sI0DKMc'
>>> signing.loads(value)
{'pk': '25'}
>>> signing.loads(value,max_age=10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/avinash/.virtualenvs/mapd/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/signing.py", line 140, in loads
    base64d = force_bytes(TimestampSigner(key, salt=salt).unsign(s, max_age=max_age))
  File "/home/avinash/.virtualenvs/mapd/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/signing.py", line 209, in unsign
    'Signature age %s > %s seconds' % (age, max_age))
django.core.signing.SignatureExpired: Signature age 25.847949981689453 > 10 seconds
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function() {
  // Replace each URL
  $(".exampleclass").each(function(index) { 
    // Get current URL
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
    // Encode URL
    var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(url);
    // Replace
    $(this).attr("href", encodedUrl); 
  });
});
```

This is the original URL:

```
http://10.91.161.54:8181/validate_/listActivi/314/
```

This is the URL with replacement:

```
http://10.91.161.54:8181/validate_/%2Fvalidate_%2FlistActivi%2F314%2F%20
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't this be sitting on the client where javascript can be potentially deactivated?

Comment: Answer requests Django, not jQuery